# How to interpret the categorical relationship between convergent sequences and continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

I attend a math seminar at my university, and a senior professor went on the following (paraphrased) tangent

> As a side note, there's an interesting relationship between convergent sequences and continuous maps onto a topological space $X$. In fact, if you define this relationship well (can be established locally or globally), you can construct categories for both such that they are duals.

> Some student asks for more clarity

> I don't want to spend too much time here, but if you think about the indiscrete topology, all sequences converge everywhere, and only constant maps are continuous. For the discrete topology, only constant sequences converge, and all maps are continuous. Anyways, back to the topic...

I'm quite confused by this statement. I get what his examples are trying to show but I still can't see how this establishes a categorical relationship.

Comment: I think this does not work because convergent sequences are in general inadequate to characterize the topology of a space (except for *sequential spaces*) . We need the more general concepts of a *net* and of *convergence for nets*. Moreover, it is not clear what $X$ is in "continuous maps onto a topological space $X$." Does he mean the space in which the sequences or nets live or does he mean the target space of maps $f$ living on the space under consideration? Probably the second interpretation, as the second statement indicates.

Comment: @PaulFrost All good questions. I emailed him, but to no response.